# Restore Atom text space to fullscreen

Tags: atom-editor

I pressed Alt Gr + something in Atom text editor and now my window looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove this blank space on the right and restore text to full screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Itºs a known [issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11673). Workaround is to close atom and launch it using the *--clear-window-state* argument